# determine whether the given string is starts with among the array elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array and a given string.

I need an efficient and fast way to check whether the string match is present in the array as starting item.

for example,

```
array_to_search = ["systematic plan","superscript", "subset"]
```

if string_to_search = "systematic"
This should return true

if string_to_search = "super"
This should return true

if string_to_search = "matic"
This should return false

if string_to_search = "plan"
This should return false

if string_to_search = "mmatic"
This should return false

if string_to_search = "superset"
This should return false

if string_to_search = "superscript"
This should return true

if string_to_search = "script"
This should return false

**I have tried with**

```
array_to_search.contains("superset")
Error: contains is not a function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array#some` with `startsWith` to check if given pattern is in string at beginning.

```
array_to_search.some(search => search.startsWith(string_to_search))
```

```js
const array_to_search = ["systematic plan","superscript", "subset"],
      string_to_search = ["systematic", "super", "matic", "mmatic", "superset", "superscript", "script"],
      result = string_to_search.map(string => array_to_search.some(search => search.startsWith(string)));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

For *boolean operations/validation* on list structures does JavaScript feature the array methods [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)...

```js
function doesAnyStringItemStartWith(arr, search) {
  return arr.some(item => item.startsWith(search));
}
const array_to_search = [
  'systematic plan',
  'superscript',
  'subset'
];

[
  'systematic',
  'super',
  'matic',
  'plan',
  'mmatic',
  'superset',
  'superscript',
  'script'

].forEach(search => console.log(

  `doesAnyStringItemStartWith(array_to_search, '${ search }') ?`,
  doesAnyStringItemStartWith(array_to_search, search)
));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```